# What to do for sendEvent method of UIApplication is duplicated in iOS7?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, tweak, cydia-substrate

I hook `sendEvent` method of `UIApplication` to get events in iOS 6, but it crashed in iOS 7. I've tried `handleKeyUIEvent`, `handleEvent`, `_handleHIDEvent`, only `handleKeyUIEvent` can get the key events, the others get nothing but don't crash like `sendEvent`. What can I do to get touch events in iOS 7?

```
%hook UIApplication
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent*)event
    //.......
    %orig;
}
```

%end